# How to SET Doctype from server side (asp.net)

Tags: html, asp.net, doctype

I have am migrating clients one by one from using an old doctype into using a newer one.
Old doctype: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">`
New doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

In the page load of the page I check the database and based on the db flag I need to set to the request one or the other.

How can I set the doctype for the page from server side?

What I am doing so far is at the top of the .aspx: `<%= DocType %>` and on the server side, in page load I load the protected variable named DocType.
Although this is working, I am having other problems with it,s o i need some other way of doing it.

I tried this: `<%# DocType %>` but didn't work.

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using master pages?

Comment: Not master pages, since this is an old application, but something similar... All pages inherit from one page, and that page makes generic edits to the rendering of all pages and other stuff in the page_load as well.

Comment: Difficult to give an answer, you say that the `<%= DocType %>` work but you have other problems that you do not tell us, you say that have the old doc type, but how the old doc type is rendered on page ? Can you simple change the old doc type ?